# Memory error while writing C code to "remove" sub-array from a larger array

Tags: c, arrays

I came across a code problem which asked of me to write a C code that removes all instances of a sub-array from a larger array. For example, if I had two arrays that looked like

```
   int arr1[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,9,10};
   int arr2[3] = {1,2,3};
```

the function should "remove arr2" from arr1 two times, because as you can see there are two instances of it in arr1.

Now, I wrote a code that "works". What I did was I wrote a separate function to determine if the smaller array is a sub-array of the larger one. For that I used temporary pointers. Each time the sub-array is found, I pass other parameters to another function which actually does the removal of the sub-array from the larger array. I figured that to remove the sub-array, I only need to remove the element at position `position` `number` of times, and the `number` is the size of the smaller array(sub-array).

It works each time I tried it but the compiler I used on an online server detected a memory error in one of the lines(I'll promptly add comments so my code is more readable). A word of forewarning, though.

I am restricted to using only what I used here, arrays(no indexing allowed) and pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*
Basically, the "remove_subarray" function accepts the array where I need to remove elements
"position" parameter is the position of the element I need to remove
exactly "number" times.

pp1 = is used to determine the starting position for the removal
pp2 - points after the end of the array
counter - to ensure the removal is performed "number" of times




*/



int remove_subarray(int *p1, int *p2, int position, int number)
{
    int *pp1 = p1+position;  int *pp2 = p2;
    int counter;
    for(counter=0; counter<number; counter++)
    {
        for(; pp1<(pp2-1); pp1++) // basic loop for
        {
            *pp1 = *(pp1+1);      // deletion of element
        }
        pp1=p1+position;  // <--- I use this to reset the pointer
                          // back to its original position
    }
    return p2-p1;         //  return the size of the first array
}


     /*
     p1 and p2 border the first array, q1 and q1 border the smaller array
     pp1, pp2, pq1, pq2 are temporary pointers;

     px and py are used when I actually iterate through both arrays
     to determine if it is a subarray or not, so i don't lose track of
     the starting positions



     */


int identify_subarray( int *p1,  int *p2,  int *q1,  int *q2)
{
     int *pp1 = p1, *pp2 = p2, *pq1 = q1, *pq2 = q2;
     int *px, *py;
    int size=0;
    while(pp1<pp2) // iterate through first array
    {

        if(*pp1 == *pq1) // if current element of first array
                        //is equal to first element of smaller array
        {
            py=pq1;    //set the values for two temporary pointers
            px = pp1;
            while(*px == *py) //***THE MEMORY ERROR IS HERE**
                // iterate while they are equal
            {
                if(py == (q2-1) && *py == *px) // IF  py points to 
                                      // last element of second array
                                      // and if it is equal to the current
                                      //pointee of px,
                                      //then I found the subarray!
                {
                    size+=(q2-q1); // for every subarray found, 
                            //i need to subtract the size of the second array
                            //from the first one, because if one subarray is found
                            //i actually remove "n" elements from the first
                            //where "n" is the size of the second
                    remove_subarray(p1, p2, pp1-p1, q2-q1);
                }
                px++; 
                py++;
            }
        }

        pp1++;


    }


    return size;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    int arr1[12] = {1,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,9};
    int arr2[1] = {9};
    n=12;
    int a=identify_subarray(arr1, arr1+12, arr2, arr2+1);
    n=n-a;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, as I said, it works every time I tried it, but the compiler says my program has a memory error.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Profiler message:

```
PROFILER:
==29332== exp-sgcheck, a stack and global array overrun detector
==29332== NOTE: This is an Experimental-Class Valgrind Tool
==29332== Copyright (C) 2003-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks Ltd et al.
==29332== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29332== Command: bs_test_1262
==29332== Parent PID: 29331
==29332== 
==29332== Invalid read of size 4
==29332== at 0x400708: identify_subarray(bs_test_1262.c:41)
==29332== by 0x40089F: main (bs_test_1262.c:88)
==29332== Address 0xfff000c2c expected vs actual:
==29332== Expected: stack array "arr2" of size 12 in frame 1 back from here
==29332== Actual: unknown
==29332== Actual: is 0 after Expected
==29332== 
==29332== Invalid read of size 4
==29332== at 0x400708: identify_subarray(bs_test_1262.c:41)
==29332== by 0x40089F: main (bs_test_1262.c:88)
==29332== Address 0xfff000c20 expected vs actual:
==29332== Expected: unknown
==29332== Actual: stack array "arr2" of size 12 in frame 1 back from here
==29332== 
==29332== 
==29332== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Running this code on my machine produces no errors and valgrind is saying that it seems okay. What is the full error message you are getting?

Comment: @tbejos thanks for answering. i edited my question to include the message of the profiler. Also, I get an "Access to uninitialized value" error. Does it possibly have to do something because the element to be removed in my example is "9" and it is located at the end of the first array?

Comment: The only sketchy thing I see is that you do not bounds-test `py`.  So it's entirely possible to iterate off the end of the `q` array and then later try to dereference that pointer if the inner loop doesn't find what it was looking for.  As an aside, there's no need to have two loops in `remove_subarray`.  Just have a single loop and shuffle the values by `number` instead of `1`.

Comment: By the way, a ghetto way to test for buffer overflow is to increase the size of your buffer and write specific values into the empty space.  Then examine that data later and see if those values have been modified.  If so, you have buffer overflow, which could definitely lead to the type of stack corruption error you're seeing.

Comment: You can change the `while` in this way:
`while((printf("--%p-%p (%u-%u)\n", px, py, *px, *py), 1) && *px == *py) //***THE MEMORY ERROR IS HERE**`
and add the following to `main()`:`printf("==%p-%p\n", arr1+12, arr2+1);` The output will be: `==000000000061FE10-000000000061FDE0
--000000000061FE0C-000000000061FDDC (9-9)
--000000000061FE10-000000000061FDE0 (6-1)
1 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 3 1 2` So you read the data after the end of both arrays

Comment: Please use more meaningful variable names, so we can understand your code better. E.g. `int identify_subarray( int *array_start,  int *array_end,  int *subarray_start,  int *subarray_end)`

Comment: You don't need nested loops in `remove_subarray()`. Instead of shifting each element down 1 position N times, shift each element down N positions. `*pp1 = *(pp1 + number)`. You could also just use `memmove(pp1, pp1+number, pp2-pp1)`. (Oops, just noticed that @paddy made my first point.)

Comment: The value of `*py == *px` is always true in the body of this loop `while(*px == *py)`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this modification of your code may help you:

```
    while(px < pp2 && py < pq2 && *px == *py) //***THE MEMORY ERROR IS HERE**
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code really make me headache

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int Int_ArrayMatch(int* a,int a_len,int* b,int b_len){
    if(b_len>a_len){
        return -1;
    }
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<a_len-b_len+1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<b_len;j++){
            if(a[i+j]!=b[j]){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j==b_len){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
int Remove_Sub_Int_Ar(int* a,int a_len,int* b,int b_len){
    int Place=Int_ArrayMatch( a,  a_len,b, b_len);
    int i;
    printf("P[%d] Is Goal\n",Place );
    if(Place<0){
        return 0;//false match not remove
    }
    for(i=Place;i<a_len-b_len;i++){
        a[i]=a[i+b_len];
    }
    return 1;

}

int main(){
    int BaseAr[12] = {1,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,9};
    int BaseAr_len=12;
    //---------------------------Below is  match example--------------
    /*
    int SearchAr[3] = {2,3,2};
    int SearchAr_len=3;*/
    /*int SearchAr[3] = {1,1,2};
    int SearchAr_len=3;*/

    int SearchAr[2] = {2,9};
    int SearchAr_len=2;
    /*int SearchAr[1] = {9};
    int SearchAr_len=1;*/

    //---------------------------Below is not match example--------------
    /*int SearchAr[3] = {1,1,1};
    int SearchAr_len=3;*/
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------


    int i;
    int Remain_len;
    if(Remove_Sub_Int_Ar(BaseAr,BaseAr_len,SearchAr,SearchAr_len)){
        Remain_len=BaseAr_len-SearchAr_len;
        for(i=0;i<Remain_len;i++){
            printf("%d\n",BaseAr[i]);
        }
    }else{
        printf("Not Match Bro!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Clearly dosen't it?

---

Give you a pointer version

```
int Int_ArrayMatch_Ver_PLoop(int* a,int a_len,int* b,int b_len){
    if(b_len>a_len){
        return -1;
    }
    int *a_start=&a[0],*a_end=&a[a_len-b_len];
    int *b_start=&b[0],*b_end=&b[b_len-1];
    int *b_temp,*a_temp;
    for(;a_start!=a_end+1;a_start++){
        for(b_temp=b_start,a_temp=a_start;b_temp!=b_end+1;b_temp++,a_temp++){
            if(*a_temp!=*b_temp){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(b_temp==b_end+1){
            return a_start-a;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}




int Remove_Sub_Int_Ar(int* a,int a_len,int* b,int b_len){
    int Place=Int_ArrayMatch_Ver_PLoop( a,  a_len,b, b_len);
    int i;
    printf("P[%d] Is Goal\n",Place );
    if(Place<0){
        return 0;//false match not remove
    }
    for(i=Place;i<a_len-b_len;i++){
        a[i]=a[i+b_len];
    }
    return 1;

}
```

don't totally use pointer at first

---

want remove all appears
do like below

```
    while(Remove_Sub_Int_Ar(BaseAr,BaseAr_len,SearchAr,SearchAr_len)){
        BaseAr_len=BaseAr_len-SearchAr_len;
        for(i=0;i<BaseAr_len;i++){
            printf("%d\n",BaseAr[i]);
        }
    }
```

---

Give you some tip:

1.Name a variable easy to view

2.Avoid while loop if you don't have 100% confidence

3.If you keep get error delete all function and re-write it from nothing

4.Right first then speed